# Any way to accomplish i++ in matlab?

Tags: c++, matlab, variables

Assuming that `srcHoughMatrix` is a 3-dimensional matrix :

Instead of

```
    if (currentRadius >= MINIMUM_ALLOWED_RADIUS )
    % we're using only radiuses that are 6 or above 
        currentHough = srcHoughMatrix(index,jindex,currentRadius);
        srcHoughMatrix(index,jindex,currentRadius) = currentHough + 1;
    end
```

How can I add `1` to each cell if the condition is true , without using a temporary variable 
or without

```
srcHoughMatrix(index,jindex,currentRadius)  = srcHoughMatrix(index,jindex,currentRadius)  + 1;
```

Thanks

Comment: Also, it's "each element", not "each cell".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not that I wouldn't do what @Jonas suggested, but what about using [`operator`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/operator.html) ? it is used to define new user-defined operator symbols or to delete them  (you will need the symbolic toolbox though).

`operator(symb, f, T, prio)` defines a new operator symbol `symb` of type `T` (Prefix | Postfix | Binary | Nary) with priority `prio`. The function `f` evaluates expressions using the new operator.

Given the operator symbol "++", say, with evaluating function `f`, the following expressions are built by the parser, depending on the type of the operator, where :

**Prefix**:     The input ++x results in f(x).

**Postfix**:    The input x++ results in f(x).

**Binary**:     The input x ++ y ++ z results in f(f(x, y), z).

**Nary**:       The input x ++ y ++ z results in f(x, y, z)).

see more at matlab's [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/operator.html).

Comment: Oh, good catch! Not having access to the symbolic toolbox (I have Mathematica for that) made me miss that completely. +1

Answer (score 5):

Matlab doesn't have the `++` operator.

However, if you would like to shorten your statement and avoid the temporary variable, you can at least write

```
srcHoughMatrix(index,jindex,MINIMUM_ALLOWED_RADIUS:end) = ... 
    srcHoughMatrix(index,jindex,MINIMUM_ALLOWED_RADIUS:end) + 1;
```

(assuming that `currentRadius` takes on all values from 1 through the 3rd-dimension-size of the array).

Comment: You should document if this answer is or is not creating a temporary.

Comment: @user2987828: ok, done. I assumed that it's obvious from the solution that there is no temporary variable being created, but it's better to be explicit. Also, Matlab does not create temporaries internally, as far as I know.