# Is is possible to implement a user-defined operator in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I am wondering if it is possible to create my own operators in MATLAB 2013a.

As an example, say that I want to define a new operator `===` to check if *all* of the elements between two matrices are equal. In this case,

```
x = ones(10,1);
y = ones(10,1);
z = 2*ones(10,1);

all(x==y) = 1
x===y = 0

all(z==y) = 0
z===y =0
```

Would it be possible to implement something like this? If so, how can I go about it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure matlab has a fixed mapping between (operator spelling) and (name of implementing function), for example that `.+` goes to `plus` and `*` goes to `mtimes`.  This system allows you to define the behavior of each operator when used on your own object types, but new operators would have to be done as ordinary functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*[taken from a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14224666/any-way-to-accomplish-i-in-matlab/14224923#14224923) of mine]*

Try using [`operator`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/operator.html). It is used to define new user-defined operator symbols or to delete them  (you will need the symbolic toolbox though).

`operator(symb, f, T, prio)` defines a new operator symbol `symb` of type `T` (Prefix | Postfix | Binary | Nary) with priority `prio`. The function `f` evaluates expressions using the new operator.

Given the operator symbol "++", say, with evaluating function `f`, the following expressions are built by the parser, depending on the type of the operator, where :

**Prefix**:     The input ++x results in f(x).

**Postfix**:    The input x++ results in f(x).

**Binary**:     The input x ++ y ++ z results in f(f(x, y), z).

**Nary**:       The input x ++ y ++ z results in f(x, y, z)).

see more at matlab's [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/operator.html).